# Contribution status for tax deduction?

Tags: contributions, best-practice

This is a question on best practice I think:

To get tax deduction for donations in Norway, the NGO has to send a report to the tax authorities (as in addition to the donor itself)

In addition to donation data in CiviCRM, we also have data from other systems. The money from those donations are already recorded in CiviCRM as they are paid out collectively at the end of the month.

Now I want to import the donations from the other systems into CiviCRM so that I get a full and accurate report for the tax authorities.

But I do not want to have the donations to be summed up double, as the transactions are already recorded.

My idea was to add another contribution status like «tax deduction» on those contributions from the external systems.

And then I could edit my tax report to include both contributions with status Completed, and Tax deduction.

And the rest of the donation reports in CiviCRM will generally be unaffacted, since they all look for contributions with status Completed.

Anyone has any thoughts on why or why not this is a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

So if I'm understanding this correctly, you currently have monthly collective totals in Civi and now want to import the detail behind those so you can do reporting at the individual level.

If you have the individual level detail to import, do you still need the monthly entries?  If not, just delete the summary ones and import the details.

If you do want both:  you suggest adding a new contribution status.  There is a lot of logic based around those statuses and I wouldn't mess with that.  But slightly changing that idea you could add a new financial type such as 'imported-monthly-total'.  Then change those monthly totals to this new type so that you can import the detailed data and in the tax reports be sure to filter by financial type to exclude 'imported-monthly-total'.

Comment: Thx for input. I thought of financial type as well, but I am worried that it is a much bigger risk of having to filter all reports based on financial types then...

Comment: And just for reference, it is no option of replacing monthly collectively with individual donations, as they don’t match up entirely (fees etc...)